# Decimal numbers cutting

Tags: string, floating-point, numbers, decimal, cut

I put a number in EditText line and it counts a double value in another.
But the double value of 4.8 should be 9.6 and not 9.6000000381469727.
I know it is normal for float but I would like to cut the amount of decimal numbers to 4. I'm not sure how to do this in my code.

```
private void calc(double number, operation input) {
        double a = 0;
        switch (input) {
        case a:
            valuedouble.setText(valuecount(number));

private String valueucount(double input) {
        return Double.toString( input*2 );
    }
```

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command (format strings)

```
String.format("%.4f", number);
```

See [this site](http://sharkysoft.com/archive/printf/docs/javadocs/lava/clib/stdio/doc-files/specification.htm) for a complete list of format strings.

Comment: Isn't this usable in iOS? I am programming for Android.

Comment: sorry, it is a bit out of scope, but I just change the sample since the format string will apply to android as well.

Comment: I tried like this:      `code`    private void calc(double number, operation input) {
  double a = 0;
     switch (input) {
  case a:
   valuedouble.setText(String.format("%.4f",valuecount(number)));`code`Although I am not getting any arror in Eclipse, it doesn't work in the app - it doesn't count and even nor in other editTexts

Comment: The format string means that you will pass a double parameter and it should be formatted as a string with maximal 4 decimal digits. In your code either the valuecount method should return a double or the Doubel.toString... call in valuecount should be replaced with the String.format... line.